# Is using Debugger a wrong course to join competition of programming?

Tags: debugging

I'm practicing programming to take part in competition of programming. I have taken part in JOI and PCK, which are popular competition of programming in Japan. But only using a simple text editor is allowed in JOI and PCK. I'm still using debugger during my practice of programming of competition. Is it a wrong course?

Answer (score 0):

If they allow you to only use a text editor then you should practice in such conditions to get used to the right rules.

Comment: Yes, I practice without using debugger when the competition is coming. But is the professional programmer of competition, such as TopCoder, uses debugger? Do they prefer debugging by inserting short statement to watch variables to debugging by debugger?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that they mean you aren't allowed to use an IDE, but that you can still use a command line debugger like GDB. I would check to see if they explicitly ban debuggers, or just IDEs.

Comment: Thank you. I will study the usage of GDB. I may have been relying on IDE too much...